# Using async await with axios

Tags: javascript, async-await

I've got a function that makes a call with axios and returns it:

```
const makeRequest = () => {
    return axios.get('/data');
}

const printResponse = () => {
    makeRequest()
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(response)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
    })
}
```

I'm trying to use async await to make this better and avoid using 'then'.

```
const makeRequest = async () => {
    return await axios.get('/data');
}

const printResponse = () => {
    try {
        const response = makeRequest();
        console.log(response)
    } catch(error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

However, despite using `await`, `makeRequest` still returns a promise, so I have to end up using `then` in my `printResponse` function anyway. Am I not using this correctly?

Comment: async will always return a promise, btw have you tried to delete async and await from make request and add them into print response in order to have response = await makeRequest()?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"However, despite using `await`, `makeRequest` still returns a promise"

Yes, of course it does. `async/await` is just syntactic sugar for working with Promises. In particular, any function marked `async` will return a Promise - this is by design.

If you don't like using `.then`, you can just as easily use `async/await` to consume this promise:

```
const printResponse = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await makeRequest();
        console.log(response)
    } catch(error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah I see. I didn't know that the return of an async function will ALWAYS be a promise. That's interesting.